# How to confirm whether different results are due to differences in floating point handling?

Tags: java, c++, floating-point

I have converted a relatively simple algorithm that performs a large number of calculations on numbers of the `double` type from C++ to Java, however running the algorithm on the two platforms but the same machine produces slightly different results. The algorithm multiplies and sums lots of doubles and ints. I am casting ints to double in the Java algorithm; the C algorithm does not cast.

For example, on one run I get the results:

- (Java) 64684970
- (C++) 65296408

(Printed to ignore decimal places)

Naturally, there may be an error in my algorithm, however before I start spending time debugging, is it possible that the difference could be explained by different floating point handling in C++ and Java? If so, can I prove that this is the problem?

---

Update - the place where the types differ is a multiplication between two ints that is then added to a running total double.
Having modified the C code, currently in both:

`mydouble += (double)int1 * (double)int2`

Comment: What data type did you use in the Java version?

Comment: That's quite a difference, and I doubt that can be caused by round-off errors. My guess is you made a mistake somewhere. Unless you do quite extreme things like dividing by 1E300 and stuff.

Comment: @Mr Lister: updated with example result.

Comment: Just throwing out some genreal thoughts here: Are the differences big? Do you have any suspicions on parts of the code that could cause rounding errors? Can the algorithm be broken up into smaller parts and run separately? Can you step through the code line by line with a debugger and see where it starts to differ?

Comment: Slightly unlikely that floating point errors would accumulate to a 1% discrepancy, but it's certainly possible if the algorithm you're running is numerically unstable ("unstable" means approximately "the kid brother of chaotic"). Obviously there's no way to tell from the results that you haven't accidentally written `result -= 611438` in your Java code, so it is not possible to prove that it *is* due to rounding errors just by looking at the results. But if you can run the calculation in C++ using `float` in place of `double`, that might give an idea how much precision matters.

Comment: Using either a debugger or print statements, display with full precision each intermediate value in your algorithm. Hopefully this will identify a single step where the values start to diverge. Come back to us when you have that single step identified.

Comment: You can also get discrepancies depending how the code is optimised. e.g. `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1` vs `5 * 0.1`  I wouldn't expect to get a difference in less than the 12th to 15th digit depending on what you are doing.

Comment: @Rob that was what I was doing next. Identified the problem, a data issue not a rounding/fp one :)

Comment: @Brabster - I'm glad you found the problem. I'm voting to close your question as "too localized".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there are times when the value of a double literal could change between two c++ compiler versions (when the algorithm used to convert the source to the next best double value changed).

Also on some cpus floating point registers are larger than 64/32bit (greater range and precision), and how that influences the result depends on how the compiler and JIT move values in and out of these registers - this is likely to differ between java and c++.

Java has the strictftp keyword to ensure that only 64/32 bit precision is used, however that comes with a run-time cost. There are also a large number of options to influence how c++ compilers treat and optimize floating point computations by throwing out guarantess/rules made by the IEEE standard.

if the algorithm is mostly the same then you could check where the first difference for the same input appears.

Comment: In this case checking the step by step output identified the divergent step and pointed me to a difference in the data. Having corrected that the algorithms agree.

Answer (score 3):

You could add rounding to each algorithm using the same precision.  This would allow each calculation to handle the data the same way.  If you use this, it would eliminate the algorithm being the problem as the data would be using the same precision at each step of the equation for both the C++ and Java versions

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, rounding might reduce the number of times there is a problem, but it wouldn't eliminate all problems? You might still roll up a precision difference into the less precise rounded float, I think? Like if on cpu gives 95.499999994 and the other gives 95.499999995 and you round at that precision, you'll get different values even though fewer decimals?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, double is a 64-bit floating-point number.
In C++, double is a floating-point number guaranteed to have at least 32-bit precision.

To find out the actual size, in bytes, of a C++ double on your system, use sizeof(double).

If it turns out that sizeof(double) == 8, it is almost certain that the difference is due to an error in the translation from one language to another, rather than differences in the handling of floating-point numbers.

(Technically, the size of a byte is platform-dependant, but most modern architectures use 8-bit bytes.)